# Port forward на внешний IP

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows

Есть сервер на windows server 2008 с белым IP. На определенном порту висел некий сервис. Сервис переехал в другое место, на другой сервер. Как смаппить порт на винсервере на другой внешний IP адрес?

Уточню цель - адрес используют железки, до которых сразу не добраться, нужно, чтобы они не заметили разницы от переезда сервиса.

Answer (score 3):

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8080 listenaddress=192.168.1.1 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.2.1
```

Это вам нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Сервер напрямую "висит" на "белом" порту? Ужас какой...
Рекомендую установить какой-нибудь маршрутизатор для обеспечения безопасности, пусть даже самый простой... А уж в нем пробросить порты до вашего сервиса - железки этого точно не заметят.

Answer (score 0):

netsh portproxy искоропки.